# Error: 'int sqlite3_open' redeclared as different kind of symbol'

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm using **C++** with **SQLite3**. I keep getting the error in my code:

> `'int sqlite3_open' redeclared as different kind of symbol`

My code is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

sqlite3 *db;

int sqlite3_open("lg.sqlite", &db);

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you think `int sqlite3_open("lg.sqlite", &db);` is doing? That looks like an attempt at a function call, and if it is, it should be inside main().

Comment: Judging from [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/122300-sqlite-in-c/) site, opening a database.

Comment: No, it isn't. You will need to learn at least a little C++ before you can use APIs like this.

Comment: Did you even look at the help documents before attempting to code it? https://sqlite.org/quickstart.html

Comment: Yes, I've studied the quickstart page for ages. I have also scoured stackoverflow but to no avail.

Comment: "Yes, I've studied the quickstart page for ages"  - you must have reading difficulties then - your code looks nothing like their code. Hint - copy and paste their code.

Comment: I couldn't get the any examples one working so I tried to combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in short, and my C++ is rusty since you did the "include" of sqlite3.h this already has the definition of the sqlite3_open().  Therefore the compiler sees your additional `function` and throws the error.

So, if you actually see the `sqlite3 *db;` is basically a global (this has can have unforeseen consequences) at this point but then you dropped 
`int sqlite3_open("lg.sqlite", &db);`

what it should look like... **directly from the sample in the docs**

```
int main(){
   sqlite3 *db;
   sqlite3_open("lg.sqlite", &db);

  return 0;
}
```

this opens the db ready for your next command.

Comment: Thankyou, this works perfect. I tried this but it didn't work. Probably because I'm stupid. But either way, thanks.

Comment: Not stupid just miss understanding of the language/system keep reading the docs and C++ is not an easy language.